# testing and mocking pubsub subscription and channel in golang

Tags: go

I am trying to learn go, I have a Java background. What I am trying to accomplish is the ability to mock pubsub and when a message is received a channel sends a message.

What I am finding hard is the fact that the method has no params. I have to Mock pubsub `Receive` and in that method send a mock message over a channel.

when I run

```
go test ./... --cover
```

I currently get 0%

method to test

```
func (s *Service) Consume() error {
    subscription := os.Getenv("OUTO_PUBSUB_SUBSCRIPTION")
    sub := s.Client.Subscription(subscription)

    ctx := context.Background()

    err := sub.Receive(ctx, func(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {
        msg.Ack()
        fmt.Println(msg.Data)
        s.messageChannel <- string(msg.Data)
    })

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return fmt.Errorf("sub.Receive: %v", err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

pubsub test

```
func TestConsume(t *testing.T) {
    // create channels
    testChan := make(chan string, 100)
    service := Service{messageChannel: testChan}
    sending := service.messageChannel
    sending <- "Test message"

    t.Run("Test when consume runs a message is sent via channel", func(t *testing.T) {
        got := <-sending
        want := "Test message"
        if want != got {
            t.Fatalf("wanted %v, got %v", want, got)
        }
    })

}
```

I am able to get the channel test to work but I need to call the Consume method so the go framework knows I am actually testing against it.

advice?

---

Answer provided but run into an issue mocking Pubsub client. When implementing the mock client it just hangs and the test never finishes and when using the MockClient struct the IDE complain it is not type of pubsub.Client

```
type MockClient struct {
}

type MockSubscription struct {
}

func (mc MockClient) Subscription() MockSubscription {
    return MockSubscription{}
}

func (ms MockSubscription) Receive(ctx context.Context, f func(context.Context, *pubsub.Message)) error {
    /* create the message you're mocking you're receiving here */
    /* you might have to mock the message struct and its interface if you want to validate that it has be ACKed */
    msg := new(pubsub.Message)
    f(ctx, msg)
    // return an error or not i'll be returning nil for now
    return nil
}

func TestConsume(t *testing.T) {

    conn, err := grpc.Dial("myMockServerAddress", grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: Handle the error
    }
    ctx := context.Background()
    // Now create the pubsub client with the grpc conn
    client, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, "mockProject", option.WithGRPCConn(conn))

    // create channels
    testChan := make(chan string, 100)
    //when MockClient{} is here a error occurs Cannot use 'MockClient{}' (type MockClient) as the type *pubsub.Client
    service := Service{messageChannel: testChan, Client: client}
    sending := service.messageChannel
    sending <- "Test message"

    t.Run("Test when consume runs a message is sent via channel", func(t *testing.T) {
        service.Consume() // run the function so you can test it
        got := <-sending
        want := "Test message"
        if want != got {
            t.Fatalf("wanted %v, got %v", want, got)
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tedious but you'd have to create a mock of your `Service` struct and it's associated interface.
Below is an example, you may have to change it to match the interface properly.

```golang
type MockClient struct {
}

type MockSubscription struct {
}

func (mc MockClient) Subscription(sub string) {
    return MockSubscription{}
}

func (ms MockSubscription) Receive(ctx context.Context,f func(context.Context, *pubsub.Message)) error {
    /* create the message you're mocking you're receviing here */
    /* you might have to mock the message struct and its interface if you want to validate that it has be ACKed */
    msg := new(pubsub.Message)
    f(ctx, msg)
    // return an error or not i'll be returning nil for now
    return nil
}


func TestConsume(t *testing.T) {
    // create channels
    testChan := make(chan string, 100)
    service := Service{messageChannel: testChan, Client: MockClient{}}
    sending := service.messageChannel
    sending <- "Test message"

    t.Run("Test when consume runs a message is sent via channel", func(t *testing.T) {
            service.Consume() // run the function so you can test it
            got := <-sending
            want := "Test message"
            if want != got {
                    t.Fatalf("wanted %v, got %v", want, got)
            }
    })

}
```

Comment: thank you very much for this example. I am getting an error that reads ```Cannot use 'MockClient{}' (type MockClient) as the type *pubsub.Client``` when it is defined in the ```Service```. So I tried something else but now the test just hangs. I updated my post.

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure that you implement the proper interface for the client. From what i see the test blocks because you're creating an actual connection not a mocked one (i.e. it goes and connects to your grpc server/connection). The test can work but you need to have a server that will run  and send the data you need for your tests, and error out predictably